# How can I run mfile script in a function just one time?

Tags: matlab-guide

How can I run MFile script in a function just one time?

I mean I need a lot of data(cell,opt,polynomail,...) pulled from that MFile and to reduce calculation burden on CPU I want to run it just one time and save it to the base workspace and load it from there every time I want.

Can any body help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it using `assignin`.  Once the function is run and code executed, `assignin` the variables to the `base` workspace.

To run the function once, there is a callback that executes once: `*_OpeningFcn`.  That is the simplest, though you can add buttons and menu items and disable them once the function is executed 1 time.